# How to get Class caller name ?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

my question is simple, but I don't know how to do .

I have in a Table a method, I want to get the class caller.

I used this code :

```
Args _args = new Args();
```

but I dont' know how to use for get the name class.

thanks all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use this method to get the name or classId.

```
Args args = new Args();

args.caller(SalesFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::Invoice));

info(strFmt("%1", classId2Name(classIdGet(args.caller()))));
```

Specifically this:

> `classId2Name(classIdGet(args.caller()))`

Answer (score 1):

try to use:

**_args.caller().name()**

Example:

if (_args.caller() && _args.caller().name() == classstr(LogisticsLocationSelectionLookup))
{
...
}

See this Link:

http://kiwiaxguy.blogspot.com.br/2011/02/checking-to-see-if-caller-is-form.html

Comment: This could cause a runtime error if the `caller()` object does not contain a `name()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have access to the caller from a table method, unless you explicitly serve it as a parameter to the method.

Well, there is `xSession::xppCallStack()` but it should used for [debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfp/archive/2013/10/02/x-debugging-tips-and-tricks-2-xsession-xppcallstack.aspx) or diagnostic only.